Understanding this LeoLabs plot of (the most recent) Long March upper stage breakup debris field


We’re actively monitoring and analyzing the breakup event in #LEO involving a Chinese rocket body, CZ-6A. Our radar data indicates this event occurred on 6 August at ~20:10 UTC at ~810 km.
It resulted in at least 700 debris fragments and potentially more than 900.

Tweeted August 9, 2024 https://x.com/LeoLabs_Space/status/1821674976245670386
The upper plot shows Doppler radial velocity vs time, and the lower plot shows range vs time. About 1700 seconds (28 minutes) of continuous contacts is shown as tight curved bands of color dots. Also shown are gray and black solid smooth lines presumably representing trajectories of single, known objects.
An idea of the systems likely to have produced this data can be gleaned at https://leolabs.space/radars/
Question: Understanding this LeoLabs plot of (the most recent)  Long March upper stage breakup debris field;
I'm trying to understand if each dot represents a single sighting (could be many sightings of a few objects) or an individually identified unique object.

The recent event is covered in all the major space news websites and CNN. Be careful when searching for it because it seems there are several upper stage debris fields in the news from Long March 5B and 6A upper bodies. They seem to have a propensity to do this.
E pluribus unum comes to mind.

Ex uno plurima

@StevePemberton that's good to know in general, but I've asked how to read this diagram, not how to search google for "newer articles". Is there a chance this comment was meant to be posted elsewhere?

@StevePemberton oh I understand! I was eluding to the fact that this happens all to often - it was sarcasm; poking fun at CSAs spent upper stages' propensity to blow up and generate debris fields at long-lived and well-used altitudes when they (presumably) shouldn't.

LeoLabs has a collection of articles they've written about how they analyzed previous breakup events at https://leolabs.space/leopulse/ . Two of them show some of the graphs their software makes for their analysts to use.  From reading those, and the years I spent doing this stuff myself for someone else, I conclude that each dot is thought to be a unique object, but none are "individually identified" with confidence.
https://leolabs.space/article/detecting-a-breakup-event-in-leo/ describes the breakup of a Japanese H-2A rocket body on 12 July 2020.  It says, "When an object is detected during a radar pass, multiple measurements are collected over a period of a few seconds while the object is in the radar’s field of view."  The detailed plots show a total of 9 seconds of data, at a rate of what looks like 8 measurements per second(1).  Not all of those time bins have signal in them:  the first plot, of the object before it broke up, looks like about 22 measurements in a bit under 3 seconds.  There is also an animation of the object passing through the radar field of view (FOV), which appears as two red fans.  This would give a few seconds of data from one radar, and then after a minute or two, a few seconds of data from the other radar at the same location(2).
https://leolabs.space/article/analysis-of-the-cosmos-1408-breakup/ describes the Russian ASAT test that destroyed Cosmos 1408 on 15 November 2021.  It has a table showing the number of passes and number of measurements over several time periods.  Dividing these by each other gives an average of 17 to 26 measurements per pass, which is nicely consistent with the other article.  It says, "Subsequent radar passes over the next two days increased the number of detected fragments significantly. As of this writing [three days later], we’ve detected nearly 300 unique fragments", but also "Within a day of the Russian ASAT test, the 18th Space Control Squadron notified the general public that they had initially detected around 1500 possible associated objects from this impact." Even better, it includes a lovely graph of the same kind as the tweeted image, with one very useful addition:

The text box on the right highlights a single point, identified only as "cluster index 216", representing seven measurements (see Footnote 1 for what "one measurement" probably means) within a second or two.  Those 7 do not necessarily all go together, and there may have been more at that time which should have belonged but were missed, but they are very clearly not related to any of the other clusters on the graph, because no object in that orbit could possibly stay in this radar's extremely narrow field of view for more than a few seconds.
Therefore, I conclude that the horizontal spread of the dots almost surely represents different objects, but the vertical spread of the dots might include multiple sightings of the same object.  However, the bigger the spread, the more likely they are to be different objects seen at the same time.  I would not call any of these uniquely identified, because that implies we knew which fragment was which, and could confidently associate a single cluster in this pass with another single cluster in each of the next several passes.  This is hard, and in this case the graph annotation agrees with me:  the catalog number and name of the identified fragment is shown as "0 UNKNOWN".
Footnotes
1:  One measurement does not mean one radar pulse!  I don't know the details of their radars, but typically such things produce thousands of pulses per second, and some do a lot more.  I also don't know how they process the data, but in general a single pulse does not give good results, because the noise is too high.  You have to build up a group of pulses on the same object, and combine them statistically to make a joint estimate of the object's state.  For a stationary target, you could keep averaging forever and the answer would keep getting better, but a LEO satellite is a very non-stationary object!  You have to make a compromise between using enough pulses to give a good average, but not too many pulses or the object's state will change so much from beginning to end that the average doesn't mean what you want it to anymore.  The trickiest part is that when you form these groups of pulses, how do you tell which pulses go together for each individual object, without mixing them up?  This is called pulse deinterleaving, and it is not easy.
2:  The two fans are not the edges of a single FOV, but each the entire FOV of one of the two separate radars at the same ground site, which are both visible in the photographs on https://leolabs.space/radars/ .  Those photos do not look like normal phased-array radars.  Scroll down to the "Poker Flat Incoherent Scatter Radar" in Alaska, that was built by a different company for a different customer ten years before LeoLabs had built any radars of their own. That is what a phased array usually looks like: a big, flat, squareish plate with thousands of tiny elements carefully arranged in a grid across the surface.  All of the others, the ones LeoLabs built, are one-dimensional radars, because the array is a line, not a polygon.  The reflectors are curved perpendicular to the array, but flat parallel to it, because they're only supposed to reflect signal perpendicular to the array, not along it.  The orbit view in https://leolabs.space/article/analysis-of-the-cosmos-1408-breakup/ shows the difference in FOV.  The Texas site has only one linear array, so it has only one fan.  Just at its left edge, you can see the corners of the two separate New Zealand linear arrays poking around from the other side of the globe.  The Costa Rica site also has two linear arrays, but oriented so their fans form an X.  The Alaska site, however, has a big six-pointed star volume rather than a blade edge, because it's a standard two-dimensional array.
